# gmail stripping inline css from table

Tags: html, css, gmail, inline

I have the following html that works in MS Mail, outlook, ios but not with gmail.  I thought placing the css as inline would fix the problem but it doesn't. The two problems are the text size appears too big. I'm wondering if there is a way to have gmail use a different font size then the other email clients.  Also I need a blank line in the table and use &nbsb inside a  but this appears as just &nbsb text in gmail.

UPDATE: fixed the &nbsp with    But fontsize even with !important not working. It seems in gmail the margin:0 auto for the table is not working in gmail

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>

</header>

<body lang=EN-US>
  <div style="text-align:center;margin:0 auto;font-size:5vw">
     <img src="cid:swb-image"> 

     <h3 style='padding-left:10px;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0%;padding-top:0;text-align:left'> Hi firstname, </h3>
     <table style='text-align:left;margin:0 auto;'  >
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>
         <col style='width:6%'>

        <tr>
           <td colspan='12' style='text-align:center'><h3 style='margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:0'> msg1</h3><h4 style='margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:0'>msg2 </h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan='3'>DATE:</td>
           <td colspan='9'>datex</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan='3'>SKIPPER:</td>
           <td colspan='9'>skipperx</td>  
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan='3'>BOAT:</td>
           <td colspan='9'>boat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan='3'>STATUS:</td>
           <td colspan='9' style='color:colorx'>status</td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr><td>&nbsp</td></tr> -->
        <tr>
           <td colspan='4'>&nbsp</td>
           <td colspan='4' style='text-align:center;'>Start</td>
           <td colspan='4' style='text-align:center;'>END</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan='4'>ressailxcl:</td>
           <td colspan='4' style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>start</td>
           <td colspan='4' style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>end</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan='12' style='text-align:center'><h5 style='margin-bottom:1%;'>Click on link to update your availability</h5></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td colspan='4' style='text-align:left;'><a style='text-decoration:none;' href='mailto:skipemail'>
              <img src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/email-32.png"  style="width:32px;height:32px;border:0;"></a></td>

           <td colspan='4' style='text-align:center;'><h5> <a href='http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper'>SwB link</a></h5></td>

           <td colspan='4' style='text-align:right';><a style='text-decoration:none' href='tel:skipphone'>
              <img src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/phone-32.png"  style="width:32px;height:32px;border:0;"></a></td>  

        </tr> 

     </table>
  </div>
  <div>

       <!--skipmsg-->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: the table size is too large, the text size is too large, &nbsb comes out as text instead of a blank space

Comment: whats the ouput in gmail .. please provide screenshot

Comment: Could always try adding !important after the CSS rule. It's not a good way out but if it works you atleast know something is overwriting it. &nbsp should also be &nbsp; with the semi-colon at the end, not sure why it would write out as text either way but worth a try.

Comment: You did not set any font-size or width for table? Is that something you might have forgotten?

Comment: no, the font size is set in the div which contains the table

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was really just:

```
font-size:5vw;
```

In gmail it's just too large but in other places the 5vw was working just fine.

The solution, within style tags I added:

```
font-size:5vw!important
```

and in the inline css for the div changed the size to 16px.  So, in browsers that need the 5vw (they accept the style tag) they get that size and in places that don't accept the style tags they get 16px.  Ugly, but it works